# Javascript access object property in method

Tags: javascript, oop

how do I get this reference right, it returns "foo undefined";

```
function myObject(){
    this.foo="bar"

    this.foo2=this.myMethod.foo3;

    alert(this.foo2);
}

myObject.prototype.myMethod= {
    foo3:'foo'+this.foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this...

```
myObject.prototype.myMethod=
{
foo3:'foo'+this.foo;
}
```

the value of `this` is being evaluated from the current context where the object is being created, which likely doesn't have a `foo` property.

---

Not sure why you're calling it `myMethod`, but assigning an Object, but if you actually made it a method, you could then get the correct `foo` value.

```
function myObject(){
    this.foo="bar"
    this.foo2=this.myMethod();
    alert(this.foo2);
}
myObject.prototype.myMethod= function() {
    return 'foo'+this.foo;
};
```

```
var o = new myObject(); // alerts "foobar", and returns the new object
```

Answer (score 0):

`'foo' + this.foo` is immediately concatenated when it's parsed, so it's pretty useless (`this` does not refer to an instance).

To get an object which contains variables at the time you want to fetch it, you have to use functions. The function will only execute when you call it, so `this.foo` refers to the correct value.

```
function myObject(){
    this.foo="bar";
    this.foo2=this.myMethod().foo3;
    alert(this.foo2);
}

myObject.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    return {
        foo3: 'foo'+this.foo
    };
};
```

Comment: Ok I thought there may be a simpler way of doing it

Comment: @user1209203: It depends what you find "simple". You could define a getter which would make your original code possible (without the `()`), but the implementation is a little bit more complex.

Comment: I just thought there maybe be a 'route' to it somehow using normal object notation, maybe using parent.

Comment: @user1209203: In fact, getters do allow some kind of "routing" - you can get `this.myMethod.foo3` working with them: http://jsfiddle.net/DyrUq/.

Comment: ok thanks, I think it's neater just as a function inside the object though